# obtain top and bottom x% and assign numbers in R

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain the value where the top 10% and bottom 10% of observations lie. When I plot the density, I want to identify the observations at the bottom 10% and top 10% - I then want to either assign a "-1" to all observations that are below the bottom 10% and a "+1" to all observations to the top 10% and everything else just a "0".

```
plot(density(as.numeric(test$pr.lm)))
```

This code does what I want but only for observations less tan 0.5 and greater tan 0.5, I want to convert these into "percentages".

```
test$pred.lm <- ifelse(test$pr.lm < 0.5, "-1",
                       ifelse(test$pr.lm > 0.5, "1", "0"))
```

Data:

```
pr.lm <- c(`2018-10-03` = 0.423462496856153, `2018-10-04` = 0.427913898978011, 
`2018-10-05` = 0.404934696139578, `2018-10-08` = 0.446317322918278, 
`2018-10-09` = 0.497167887579, `2018-10-10` = 0.483608339493601, 
`2018-10-11` = 0.506296752048131, `2018-10-12` = 0.620769108097577, 
`2018-10-15` = 0.641401086662484, `2018-10-16` = 0.647211253697089, 
`2018-10-17` = 0.624948223534579, `2018-10-18` = 0.706720641849297, 
`2018-10-19` = 0.678927972325959, `2018-10-22` = 0.594686934902609, 
`2018-10-23` = 0.586573168581061, `2018-10-24` = 0.481744214817579, 
`2018-10-25` = 0.501879874108935, `2018-10-26` = 0.638941662227341, 
`2018-10-29` = 0.533530225556122, `2018-10-30` = 0.520026314139557, 
`2018-10-31` = 0.55841571603097, `2018-11-01` = 0.681757510274823, 
`2018-11-02` = 0.59654572803471, `2018-11-05` = 0.626287514663055, 
`2018-11-06` = 0.714443802319515, `2018-11-07` = 0.67080600584018, 
`2018-11-08` = 0.59281752403647, `2018-11-09` = 0.563390754546873, 
`2018-11-12` = 0.518030212097214, `2018-11-13` = 0.669092984178484, 
`2018-11-14` = 0.637525191976898, `2018-11-15` = 0.49706914674227, 
`2018-11-16` = 0.541251316928707, `2018-11-19` = 0.604244652770604, 
`2018-11-20` = 0.684593935690332, `2018-11-21` = 0.720398651972747, 
`2018-11-23` = 0.653974914464049, `2018-11-26` = 0.574402370856118, 
`2018-11-27` = 0.614833371923479, `2018-11-28` = 0.715942039198248, 
`2018-11-29` = 0.711536503476983, `2018-11-30` = 0.621089259799182
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `quantile()` maybe in combination w. `cut()`

```
cut(x, c(-Inf, quantile(x, c(0.1, 0.9)), Inf))
```

e.g. in your case (adding a label argument to `cut` as pointed out by Ben Bolker):

```
cuts <- c(-Inf, quantile(test$pr.lm, c(0.1, 0.9)), Inf)
test$pred.lm <- cut(test$pr.lm, cuts, labels = c(-1, 0, 1))
# and if we want to keep it as integer:
test$pred.lm <- as.integer(as.character(test$pred.lm))
```

A small example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
qs <- quantile(x, c(0.1, 0.9))
bins <- cut(x, c(-Inf, qs, Inf))
```

output:

```
> qs
      10%       90% 
-1.418241  1.278333 
> head(bins)
[1] (-1.42,1.28] (-1.42,1.28] (-1.42,1.28]
[4] (1.28, Inf]  (1.28, Inf]  (-Inf,-1.42]
3 Levels: (-Inf,-1.42] ... (1.28, Inf]
> table(bins)
bins
(-Inf,-1.42] (-1.42,1.28]  (1.28, Inf] 
          10           80           10
```

Comment: use `cut(..., labels=c("-1","0","1"))` to match the OP's desired output ...

Comment: @BenBolker you are right, didn't add the same labels. adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this Works but I have just one small problem. The labels do not label the values "correctly", I get values of 1, 2, 3 and not -1,0,1. `> head(test$pred.lm)
           pred.lm
2018-10-03       1
2018-10-04       1
2018-10-05       1
2018-10-08       1
2018-10-09       2
2018-10-10       2` - I have tried as.numeric(as.character(…))

Comment: I think I solved the issue regarding as.numeric(as.character(…)). Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I included a small adjustment as well in order to resolve it.